# Import module for pygame works for Jupiter notebook, but not in IDLE (Mac)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm using a mac and successfully installed pygame through my terminal, and when I type import pygame into a jupyter notebook, I recieve a message basically saying that the import was a success. However, when I type import pygame into IDLE, I get an error message. I noticed that when I installed pygame I got this message in my terminal: 
Requirement already satisfied: pygame in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.9.6).

Does anyone know how I can import pygame into IDLE? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you install `jupyter`? using pip or conda?

Comment: I used conda to install jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the default MacOS Python's IDLE(which doesn't have `pygame` installed)

Instead use `conda`'s IDLE.
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/idle/

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused, how do I open IDLE with conda?

Comment: In your home folder, you should see `miniconda3` folder. Inside that there would be a file with the name `IDLE`, open it and it should launch conda's IDLE that contains your `pygame` package.

Comment: I've gone through my home folder, and I have no miniconda3 folder. I do have an anaconda3 and IDLE folder, but I cannot actually launch IDLE through either of these. Does this mean I may have installed jupyter notebook with pip, or is there some other error here?

Comment: There should be `bin` folder inside `anaconda3` folder(sorry, I missed it earlier). Try launching it by double clicking on it.

Comment: correction - **Try launching the file with the name - `idle3.5` by double clicking on it. Instead of `3.5` it could be 3.6 or 3.7 depending upon the version of Python you have.